# Merging Cells Vertically in SQL Reporting 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

In **SQL Reporting 2008**, Is there a way to merge multiple cells that are adjacent to each other along a vertical column?

Answer (score 5):

In the report designer, click on your table, then at the bottom of the screen there is a window spit in two with the headings "Row Groups" and "Column Groups".  In row groups, click on the little down arrow next to the default group "table1_Details_Group" and choose to add a parent group.  Select the field you want to group on, and don't check the boxes to add a row header or footer.  A new column will be added and when you preview you will see that the cells of this column are merged vertically.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot merge cells vertically, only horizontally.

You can, however, create table groups.  Grouped data inside a table can be designed to look like merged vertical cells.

### EDIT

[INFORMATION ON MATRIX CONTROL](http://gotreportviewer.com/matrices/index.html)

Comment: That sucks. We are looking into replacing our Excel generated reports with SSRS and a lot of our reports have vertical merged cells.

Comment: You might be able to achieve what you are looking to do with the Matrix control.  Regardless, you will probably need to massage the presentation of the reports to make them look nice in reportViewer.  The best part is that you will then be able to export your ReportViewer reports to excel  :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use matrix table to do it. It force you to have a group column, however you can just set the group column visibility as Hidden. Then add new columns you needed.
see image here: ( my Month is merge cells from two rows)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA2ZL.png